# BGL BasicMatrix implementation with maps

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to calculate the shortest paths between a graph using BGL. The function I am calling is

```
boost::johnson_all_pairs_shortest_paths(g,distances);
```

where g is a custom graph type

```
typedef property<label_t, int> LabelProperty;
typedef  property<edge_weight_t,int> EdgeWeightProperty;

//graph definition
typedef adjacency_list<listS, 
                       listS, 
                       directedS,
                        property<vertex_index_t,int, 
                       LabelProperty >,
                        EdgeWeightProperty
                       > Graph;
```

and I am implementing the distances as a map of maps

```
typedef map<int,map<int,int> > DistMat;
DistMat distances;
```

so I can access distaces as distances[i][j] and can work with large graphs.

When I compile (with gcc 4.6.3), I get the following error:

/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:518:31: error: passing ‘const std::map >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int, _Tp = std::map, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::map, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Indeed if I use the [-fpermissive] option the code compiles and works. However, I would like to arrange the code so it compiles without selecting this option. I believe that the solution is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html), but I am quite lost among so many templates.

Any hints? Thank you very much in advance